# How to display array values in Dropdown list?

Tags: php, arrays, dropdown

These are the values stored in the array variable. Please, can someone tell me how can I use these values in Dropdown?

```
$tasks = get_tasks();
```

$tasks contains following values

```
   array(3) { 
        [0]=> array(2) { ["label"]=> string(0) "" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } 
        [1]=> array(2) { ["label"]=> string(20) "label1" ["value"]=> string(7) "value1" } 
        [2]=> array(2) { ["label"]=> string(23) "label2" ["value"]=> string(7) "value2" } 
        } 

<select id="tasks" name="tasks">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"<?php _e('Select a task..') ?></option>
            <?php 
            if(count($accounts) > 0) {
                foreach ($tasks as $list) {
                    echo '<option value="' .$list['value']. '" '. (($saved_tasks == $list['value']) ? "selected" : "") . '>' .$list['label'] . '</option>';
                }
            }
            else {
                echo '<p>' . _e('No Tasks'. '</p>';
            }
        }
            ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: What's the issue with the above code?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz It's working, I see the there was a typo while writing the index.

Comment: there is a typo mistake in your `else` condition

Comment: @NishantSolanki Yo ;)